# PHP: валидация формы

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, товарищи!

У меня проблема с валидацией и выводом сообщений в вид. Почему-то не работает простая проверка и сообщения не выводятся, при этом отправка минует валидацию и пишется всё это дело в базу. Вот код контроллера:

```
public function addAction()  {
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        $textLen = iconv_strlen($_POST['text']);
        if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $message = 'Некорректный e-mail';
        } else {
            if ($textLen < 10 or $textLen > 500) {
                $message = 'Текст сообщения может содержать от 10 до 500 знаков';
            }
        }
        $id = $this->model->feedbackAdd($_POST);
        if (!$id) {
            $message = 'Ошибка запроса';
        }
        $message = 'Сообщение отправлено!';
    }
    $this->view->render('Обратная связь', 0, 0, 0, $message);

    var_dump($_POST['text']);
    var_dump($message);
}
```

Ну и вид, здесь всё проще простого:

```
<h1><?= $title ?></h1>

<p><?= $message ?></p>

<form action="/feedback/add" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" />
    <textarea name="text" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" id="sendMessageButton" />
</form>
```

Вот я не могу понять, почему не выходит, поможите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Это шутка такая? Ты в жизни тоже так? сначала проверяешь что в кастрюле нет воды, а потом **все равно** ставишь её на огонь?

Comment: Вот, же бл…( Как удалить вопрос? :)

Comment: Хотя, я ведь сначала проверяю не пуста ли форма, а уже потом, далее. Или что-то не так? :)

Comment: ну без формы у тебя и не будет записи. а остальные проерки просто так в воздухе болтаются

Comment: Он всё равно пишет в базу пустые значения (кроме id и даты, т. к. они генерируются автоматом)

Comment: И правильно делает. ФОРМА у тебя НЕ ПУСТАЯ.  В ней поля есть. А сами поля ты не проверяешь

Comment: Ну точнее проверяешь, но никак  результат проверки не используешь

Comment: Уважаемый товарищ Ипатьев, ткните меня пожалуйста носом, как нужно сделать, а то у меня от этого кода уже дёргается глаз :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лично я бы вынес добавление проверку в другой метод, а ошибку кидал через `throw`. Вот как-то так, как минимум.

```
public function addAction()  {
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        try{
            $id = $this->sendFeedback($_POST);
            $message = 'Сообщение отправлено!';
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $message = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    $this->view->render('Обратная связь', 0, 0, 0, $message);
}

private function sendFeedback($details){
    if (!filter_var($details['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        throw new Exception('Некорректный e-mail');
    }
    
    $textLen = iconv_strlen($details['text']);
    if ($textLen < 10 or $textLen > 500) {
        throw new Exception('Текст сообщения может содержать от 10 до 500 знаков');
    }

    $id = $this->model->feedbackAdd($details);
    if (!$id) {
        throw new Exception('Ошибка запроса');
    }
    return $id;
}
```

Comment: Свеженько, мне нравится :) А что такое `$e` ? `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$e' (T_VARIABLE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or namespace (T_NAMESPACE) or \\ (T_NS_SEPARATOR) in…`

Comment: @Linne, прошу прощения, писал код по памяти, пропустил тип (класс) ошибки. PHP хочет знать класс ошибки. Самый общий - `Exception`. Теперь должно работать

Comment: Мы же создаём новый экземпляр класса (`new Error`), а его нема :) `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'App\Controllers\Error' not found in…`

Comment: Окей, меня память подвела и я попутал с js. Исправил `Error` на `Exception`. Теперь точно должно работать!

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'App\Controllers\Exception' not found in…` :)) Мы же всё равно создаём ))

Comment: Странно, у меня нормально работает. Но я никогда не использовал неймспейсы. Поищите в документации - это выходит за рамки этого вопроса

Comment: самый общий - это Throwable. И исключения для валидации данных не подходят

Comment: заменить `Exception` на `\Exception`

Comment: К сожалению, отказывается выводить категорически, но больше не ругается

Comment: @Ипатьев, обоснуйте

Comment: 1. Ошибка валидации формы - это не ошибка приложения. Это часть бизнес-логики. 2. Ошибки валидации выводят все вместе, а не по одной.